# How to grep Cisco interface name and all IP Addresses under that section

Tags: grep, cisco, pcregrep

This is sample of Cisco config file which I get from https://resources.intenseschool.com/mpls-basic-configuration/ and modified it a little bit to make it relevent to this question.

I saved it to `file.txt` and trying to `interface` name and all IP addresses under that section using egrep.

**`file.txt`**

```
interface Loopback0
 description ** test **
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description ** Connection to ABC **
 bandwidth 3000
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.0
 mpls ip
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip flow monitor all-traffic-monitor output
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 description ** Connection to XYZ **
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.1
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.2
!
router ospf 1
 network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.0.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
router bgp 14
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 remote-as 14
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
 network 10.0.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 redistribute static
 no auto-summary
!
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.100.10
!
```

**Desired Output**

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0

interface Ethernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.1
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.2
```

Here are a few attempts but none of them producing the output that I wanted.

**Attempt 1**

Syntax: `egrep ^interface file.txt`

Problem: No IP captured

```
[user@linux ~]$ egrep ^interface file.txt
interface Loopback0
interface FastEthernet0/0
interface FastEthernet0/1
interface Ethernet1/0
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Attempt 2**

Syntax: `egrep -A2 ^interface file.txt`

Problem: Too much data, I just want `interface` line and all IP addresses under that section

```
[user@linux ~]$ egrep -A2 ^interface file.txt
interface Loopback0
 description ** test **
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255
--
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description ** Connection to ABC **
 bandwidth 3000
--
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip flow monitor all-traffic-monitor output
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
--
interface Ethernet1/0
 description ** Connection to XYZ **
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Attempt 3**

Syntax: `egrep '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt`

Problem: Print IP Address only, I want interface name as well

```
[user@linux ~]$ egrep '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.0
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.1
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.2
 network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.0.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 remote-as 14
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
 network 10.0.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.100.10
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Attempt 4**

Syntax: `egrep '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt`

Problem: Almost work, but too much data, I just want `interface` line and all IP addresses under that section

```
[user@linux ~]$ egrep '^interface|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.0
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
interface Ethernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.1
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.2
 network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.0.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.0.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 remote-as 14
 neighbor 10.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
 network 10.0.100.0 mask 255.255.255.0
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.100.10
[user@linux ~]$
```

If there are better tools to use besides `egrep`, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne 'print "\n$_" if /interface/; print if / ip ./' file
```

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk '/interface/{print "\n"$0} / ip ./' file
```

### Output

```
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.1.1.11 255.255.255.255

interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.0

interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip flow monitor all-traffic-monitor output
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0

interface Ethernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.13.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.1
 ip helper-address 10.1.1.2
```